# Want all of the line with one single command - IFS

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script who recup the UID of a line in /etc/passwd, but only if the UID > 500. It's work but... i want to recup all of the line with only one command, and i don't know if it's possible.

Let me show you my code :

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7
do
  if [ $f3 -gt 500 ]
  then
     echo "$f1:$f2:$f3:$f4:$f5:$f6:$f7"  <<< there is a single command for that ?
  fi
done < /etc/passwd
```

Thanks for your respond :)

Comment: FYI, you can `read` into an array `read -a ARRAY_NAME`, but there is better way to do what you want like in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
awk -F: '$3>=500 {print $0}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Decide if you want `>` or `>=`. Your code translates to '>', but for this particular example, `>=` makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=: read -r -a f; do
  if (( ${f[2]} > 500 )); then
     IFS=: b="${f[*]}"
     echo "$b"
  fi
done < /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

I would read the entire line into a single variable, then split inside the loop.

```
while read line; do
    old=IFS
    IFS=:
    set -- $line
    IFS=$old
    test $3 -gt 500 || continue
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
done </etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

A bash solution:

```
while read  line
do
  arr=(${line//:/ })
  [ ${arr[2]} -gt 500 ] && echo $line
done < /etc/passwd
```

Splitting the entire record into an array and checking the 2nd index element which contains the user-id.